# How do I implement rendering an audio track in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I need to implement a component like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRqyw.png)

I couldn't find normal examples, and I'm just getting acquainted with react native, someone did mb and can show their example, or you know where you can find it on the Internet, I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific library for that, you would have to customize it as per your requirement. There is one lib which provides similar effects you can check here [react-native-audiowaveform](https://github.com/juananime/react-native-audiowaveform)

Hope this might help a bit.

Comment: To my regret, I am faced with an error when trying to install it and my knowledge is not enough to solve them. As I understood the problem is
 different versions